# how do I expose jcr node structure to authors?

Tags: aem, aem-6

Is there a way I can expose jcr node structure to authors. I have catalog data under /etc/catalog which I want to display as it is to the authors under siteadmin or miscadmin

One thing I noticed that only node which is cq:Page or cq:folder in listed in siteadmin or miscadmin(tools). How can we tweak it to accept nt:unstructured.

Comment: Which AEM version? Does it have to Classic UI or would TouchUI be acceptable as well? Please add more information.

Comment: A classic ui with aem 6.3 service pack 1

Comment: why not just have them use crx/de to view that structure? Your other option is to build an admin page and add UI to display that structure.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is only to allow them to select then u can use pathfield in the component dialog to allow them to view/select this -

The classic UI xtype `pathfield` provides the property called as `predicate`, value `nosystem` allows full repository browsing, showing node names. This i have worked with in 5.6 classic UI, this should work with 6.x classic ui. Can try this.

Reference - https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/widgets-api/index.html

[image]

If not this, you want to allow them to provide a screen for browsing then it would be to add a custom implementation and add it to one of these screens but that would a whole lot of effort to do it in classic ui.

A suggestion to use Touch UI based implementation and do a custom implementation where in u could use infinity.json to get the node structure as json then add your logic for tree based browsing of content.